# How to transpose content of multi-level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I want to ungroup the content into a flat pandas table with one row by country. Each country should have as many years as inflation values I have. I get inflation values by:

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
data = wb.download(indicator='FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG', country='all', start=2000, end=2020)
```

I get this table:

[image]

I tried with reindex, but then I get "too" many lines

```
data.reset_index()
```

I also tried by groupby and pivot

```
data.pivot_table(data, index=['country', 'year'], columns='FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG')
```

How to make this work?

Comment: try `data.pivot_table(index='country', columns='year', values='FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG')`

Comment: if that's not what you're looking for, i suggest editing your post to show the structure of your desired output (i.e. what would the row index and column index look like)

Comment: this is what i was looking for - thanks